# Solution for the heat equation that doesn't belong to the Gevrey Class

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, supremum-and-infimum, heat-equation

> Show that there exists a solution for the heat operator (in one
>   spatial variabe) that doesn't belong to the Gevrey class of order $s$
>   for all $s<2$

I already defined the Gevrey class here: [$\sup_K |\partial^{\alpha}u|\le C^{|\alpha|+1}\alpha!^s$ then $u$ is analytic for $s\le 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014603/sup-k-partial-alphau-le-c-alpha1-alphas-then-u-is-analytic-fo) but here is the definition again:

> A function $u\in C^{\infty}$ belongs to the Gevrey Class of order $s$
>   if for every compact $K$ of $\Omega$ there is a constant $C$ such that
>
> $$\sup_K |\partial^{\alpha}u|\le C^{|\alpha|+1}\alpha!^s, \ \alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_+^N$$

This exercise comes after it asks me to prove that a function on the Gevrey class is analytic, so maybe it helps in the solution of this exercise.

I've studied the general form of the solution for the wave equation but I couldn't find it to be something such that its derivatives are bound by that constant in the Gevrey Class definition.

Comment: Which variable are you referring to? Gevrey class in x, or in t, or in both (x,t)?

Comment: @timur I don't understand. I thought the gevrey class was in $s$

Comment: Gevrey class is a set of functions $u$. What is $u$ a function of?

Comment: @timur just noticed that my notes don't speciy this. On wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevrey_class, it says $u$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ . I'd say it's on $x$ only, but I'm not sure